# Dynamically setting default url in asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have been trying to set the default url but it is not redirecting to the page that I want. The `defaultUrl="admin/Home.aspx"` is keeping redirecting back to the `login.aspx` can someone please help?

Below is the code i am doing in the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="20" defaultUrl="admin/Home.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

the url after being redirected is as follows

```
/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2fHome.aspx
```

what do the `%2f` mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see it's redirecting you back to the login page because your not authenticated? I maybe wrong on that though.

The %2f is an url encoded forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

The WebConfigurationManager is the class you want to look at.

It doesn't specifically address the web.config tag you are trying to edit which is:

```
<forms loginUri="http://website.com/login.aspx" />
```

But as long as there are no restrictions on that tag this should solve your problems.

Here is the docs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx

Comment: i have another web.config file which includes                       <location path="SearchPage.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="1, 2, 3"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>